# Why can't a sub implement an interface and handle event at the same time?

Tags: .net, vb.net, interface, event-handling, language-design

Why can't a sub implement an interface and handle event at the same time?

The following gives my a syntax error:

```
Sub MySub() Handles MyButton.Click Implements MyInterface.MyMethod
End Sub
```

I know I could handle this kind of logic with another method, but that is not the point. I just want to understand the reasoning behind this.

Comment: Most coding conventions for .NET specify that interfaces should be prefixed with a capital letter `I` to indicate that they are interfaces (and to help distinguish them from classes). So, your interface would actually be called `IMyInterface`.

Comment: Sure, but that was not the point :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax error is consistent with the language grammar, in §9.2.1 of the VB language specification<sup>1</sup>:

> *SubDeclaration  ::=
>
>     [  Attributes  ]  [  ProcedureModifier+  ]  SubSignature  [  HandlesOrImplements  ]  LineTerminator
>
>     Block
>
>     End  Sub  StatementTerminator*

and

> *HandlesOrImplements  ::=  HandlesClause  |  ImplementsClause*

So only one is supported on any one method. The specification doesn't (on a quick view) include a rationale for this limitation. For that you'll need to talk to someone on the VB language design team at Microsoft.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is included with an installation of VS under ‹*VSRoot*›\VB\Specifications\1033.

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen any detailed discussion of *why* this decision was made by the VB.NET team, but to be honest, I struggle to see how this makes any sense from an OOP design perspective. Event handler methods generally shouldn't be doing any work. Rather, they should call out to *other* methods to do the heavy lifting. The other method that they call out to would be the one that implements your interface.

But it's certainly attainable if you do something like this:

```
Public MustInherit Class MyParentClass
    Protected WithEvents MyButton As Button

    Protected MustOverride Sub MySub() Handles MyButton.Click
End Class

Public Class MyDerivedClass : Inherits MyParentClass : Implements IMyInterface
    Protected Overrides Sub MySub() Implements IMyInterface.MyMethod
        ' Do something here...
    End Sub
End Class
```

Also remember that event handler methods generally have a distinctive signature; something like:

```
Public Sub MySub(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
```

which is another reason why it would be extremely uncommon for an event handler method to *also* be able to implement a method defined in an interface.

Comment: Unclear where you get "Event handler methods generally shouldn't be doing any work." from. However, a trivial forwarding method will be inlined (unless debugging set).

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but I explicitly stated that I don't want any opinion on the code example, but instead I want to understand microsofts reasoning here.

Comment: @Richard: Hmm, that's a pretty common design principle. I've heard it espoused all over the place with various justifications. The fundamental one, though, is that placing a lot of implementation code in your event handler methods ties the code very tightly with the UI. Since *that's* generally regarded as bad practice, it's not much of a leap to say that event handlers should call other methods that contain the logic or algorithms.

Comment: @codymanix: Great, then you posted your question in the wrong place. You need to ask Microsoft why they did that. There are about 2, maybe 3, people who post on this site that work on the VB.NET compiler team. No one else can tell you what Microsoft was thinking, or why. Or were you just looking for idle speculation? I'm not sure how that's helpful.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Exactly, there a microsoft people who also post here which may be able to answer the question. It is also possible that a non microsoft person knows a reason which may make a handles and a implements clause at the same time impossible.

Comment: @CodyGray: OK, in the case where there is benefit from separating UI from domain logic that makes sense, but the question only uses a UI sample of trying to implement an interface and handle an event. If that event was internal to the domain logic (nothing to do with UI) would that same advice hold?

Comment: @Richard: Ah, I see where you're coming from. The answer is not necessarily. I suppose I was just *assuming* it was UI code since that's where I spend 90% of my time. Yeah, it could potentially make sense to do this other places. I'm not the type that adheres strongly to categorical "rules" of design. I've thought since I was an infant that rules should be quite flexible.

Comment: @CodyGray: Understood -- that's why I queried it. +1 for 'I'm not the type that adheres strongly to categorical "rules" of design': every rule has exceptions.